# Out of 6 apples, 5 mangoes and 4 bananas how many selection of fruits can be made such that at least one fruit from each type is always included

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

According to me the answer should be $(6)(5)(4)-1= 119$ but given answer is $120$

I subtracted the 1 to eliminate the case where none of the fruits are picked.

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are mentioning i.e $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)2^s -1$ is when the total number of fruits is greater than $0$.
 Here fruit of each type is greater than $0$.

Number of ways of selecting at least 1 apple = 6
Number of ways of selecting at least 1 mange = 5
Number of ways of selecting at least 1 mange = 4

Total fruits = $6.5.4 = 120$

Comment: I don’t understand the first 4 lines of the answer. Is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Aditya What you didn't understand?

Comment: I used the formula $pqr-1$. Why don’t we subtract by -1?

Comment: @Aditya Because all the cases have been counted and there is no need to subtract by 1. In the formula $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)2^{s} -1$. We subtract 1 because we don't want the case that all fruits are 0 in number. Here there is no such case, Do you understand now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$120$ is the correct answer. The number of ways to pick at least $1$ apple is $6$, because we can pick from $1$ to $6$ apples. Similarly, there are $5$ ways to pick at least $1$ mango, and $4$ ways to pick at least $1$ banana. Thus, the total number of selections in which at least $1$ fruit of each type is picked is $6\cdot 5\cdot 4 = \boxed{120}$.

Comment: Isn’t the formula $(p+1)(q+1)(r+1)2^s-1$?

Comment: No, you are not allowed to have $0$ of any kind of fruit.

Comment: Exactly, that’s why I only used $pqr-1$.

Comment: Why the $-1$? All arrangements satisfy the conditions of the problem.